# Soft cosine distance between two vectors (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, cosine-similarity

I am wondering if there is a good way to calculate the *soft* cosine distance between two vectors of numbers. So far, I have seen solutions for sentences, which however did not help me, unfortunately.

Say I have two vectors like this:

```
a = [0,.25,.25,0,.5]
b = [.5,.0,.0,0.25,.25]
```

Now, I know that the features in the vectors exhibit some degree of similarity among them. This is described via:

```
s = [[0,.67,.25,0.78,.53]
     [.53,0,.33,0.25,.25]
     [.45,.33,0,0.25,.25]
     [.85,.04,.11,0,0.25]
     [.95,.33,.44,0.25,0]]
```

So `a` and `b` are `1x5` vectors, and `s` is a `5x5` matrix, describing how similar the features in `a` and `b` are.

Now, I would like to calculate the soft cosine distance between `a` and `b`, but accounting for between-feature similarity. I found this formula, which should calculate what I need:
[soft cosine formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSco3.png)

I already tried implementing it using numpy:

```
import numpy as np

soft_cosine = 1 - (np.dot(a,np.dot(s,b)) / (np.sqrt(np.dot(a,np.dot(s,b))) * np.sqrt(np.dot(a,np.dot(s,b)))))
```

It is *supposed* to produce a number between 0 and 1, with a higher number indicating a higher distance between a and b. However, I am running this on a larger dataframe with multiple vectors a and b, and for some it produces negative values. Clearly, I am doing something wrong.

Any help is greatly appreciated, and I am happy to clarify what need clarification!

Best,
Johannes

Comment: I found the "solution". The formula has been correctly implemented. Turns out that a similarity matrix that allows for asymmetric similarities (i and can be more similar to j than j is to i) can indeed produce values below 0 and above 1. Thanks again for the help -- it certainly cut off a lot of fat from my code!

Answer (score 0):

From what I see it may just be a formula error. Could you please try with mine ?

```
soft_cosine = a @ (s@b) / np.sqrt( (a @ (s@a) ) * (b @ (s@b) ) )
```

I use the `@` operator (which is a shorthand for [np.matmul](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html#numpy.matmul) on ndarrays), as I find it cleaner to write : it's just matrix multiplication, no matter if 1D or 2D. It is a simple way to compute a dot product between two 1D arrays, with less code than the usual `np.dot` function.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it on my df. Turns out it produces the exact same output as my version, including negative values. (alas, with way less complicated syntax!)

Comment: I don't understand why you only expect positives values, according to the definition of the soft cosine, it is supposed to produce values ranging from -1 to 1.

Comment: Thanks RandomGuy. With the vectors I am using and the formula above it produces values between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

`soft_cosine = 1 - (np.dot(a,np.dot(s,b)) / (np.sqrt(np.dot(a,np.dot(s,b))) * np.sqrt(np.dot(a,np.dot(s,b)))))`

I think you need to change: the denominator has both "a" and both "b".

`soft_cosine = 1 - (np.dot(a,np.dot(s,b)) / (np.sqrt(np.dot(a,np.dot(s,a))) * np.sqrt(np.dot(a,np.dot(s,b)))))`.

Comment: Can you please specify how to calculate the "S" similarity matrix between the two vectors?